# Xcode 11. SceneDelegate func willConnectTo. Not accepting a func with Properties

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift5, rootviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

I want to insert a func(configureInitialViewController()) into willConnectTo ( so I can recall the same func in other ViewControllers )

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        configureInitialViewController()

}

    func configureInitialViewController() {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            if 1>0 {
                window.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: ViewController1)
            } else {
                window.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: ViewController2)
            }
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please give us more details and let us know what the question is. Are you getting an error?  What is it?

Comment: Looks to me like you need to pass `scene` to your func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
func configureInitialViewController()
```

To

```
func configureInitialViewController(_ scene: UIScene)
```

And pass `scene` to it

Comment: Hey, the parameter works in the SceneDelegate. But it doesn't work in other VCs. eg: @IBAction func signInButonTapped(_ sender: Any, scene: UIScene) {
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! SceneDelegate).configureInitialViewController(scene)

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: The console gave a very long error. the error occurs when I try to recall the configureInitialViewController(_ scene: UIScene) in another view controller. But it's ok, because I used a segue to move between VCs.